# AWS Lightsail control plugin (lightsailctl) not showing as installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to follow the Amazon tutorial on how to serve a flask app with Amazon Lightsail containers but I'm getting stuck whenever I try to push the container to Lightsail. I followed Amazon's instructions to install the Lightsail Control Plugin exactly but it doesn't seem to be working. I downloaded the file, saved it to the temp folder and then opened my command line as an administrator. When I run the following code: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Temp\lightsailctl" /M` it spits back "SUCCESS: Specified Value was saved." but when I go to try and push a container image in my virtual environment I get the message: "The Lightsail Control (lightsailctl) plugin was not found. To download and install it, see [https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-install-software."](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-install-software.%22) This is the code I use to push it, copied from the tutorial:

```
aws lightsail push-container-image --service-name flask-service --label flask-container --image flask-container
```

I've tried restarting my computer. I've tried running the file directly as an administrator. I'm wondering if it's because I'm working in a virtual environment and need to install it in the virtual environment instead of globally but if that's it then I don't know how to do that. Is there an easier way to do this outside of the powershell?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **C:\Temp** instead of **C:\Temp\lightsailctl**

or

Try putting the lightsailctl.exe file in another folder that already is in your PATH variable.